# Cant see the sysssislog table on SQL Server after enabling logging on the package

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I enabled logging on one of my packages and pointed it to SQL Server. I confirmed that I added logging for OnError, OnPreExecute and OnPostExecute events and the package runs fine. But when I go over to SSMS to view the results, I dont see the table itself with MSDB or any other databases.

What am I missing??

Comment: Go to SQL Management, go to database which you use to log SSIS log, and run : select * from SysSSISLog

Are the result appears?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind. I was looking at the wrong database. I thought that sysssislog table was created by default on the msdb database, but turns out it was created within a different database.

If you face a similar issue, you would want to look for a few things:

1) If any of the events are being captured or not within the Logging window. Make sure the appropriate tasks are being logged and the appropriate details within are also being captured.

2) Check the connection string and make sure that you have appropriate permissions on the database that you are writing to.

3) If you still dont see it working, try a different logging method (writing to a text file) and this should clear up if permissions are an issue or if its something else.

Comment: Just in case someone else is trying to find the same problem, why don't you go ahead and edit your answer with the name of the database and any searches / online resources that helped you find it?

Comment: Thank you. I discovered this myself, but yes, someone else could use the same steps to debug the problem.

Comment: Just wanted to mention "You may experience decreased performance if you log to a system database such as master or msdb."

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2027706/sql-server-integration-services-package-logging-to-a-system-database-m